# PHP: Store String in array along with how many times it was added?

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible to store String in array along with number?

For example:

```
array("bob" => 2,
  "billy" => 5);
```

This is my array,Whenever new bob or billy gets added - their number goes up by 1. Then also I would like to get element that has highest number, so in this case - Billy as he was added 5 times.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: *How can I do this in PHP?* I guess try it!

Comment: Time to read Php Docs.. :) Read PHP Arrays basic docs and Array sorting ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$counters = [
    "bob" => 2, 
    "billy" => 5
];

function addNew($newWhat, &$counters) {
    $newWhat = strtolower($newWhat);
    if (isset($counters[$newWhat])) {
        $counters[$newWhat]++;
    } else {
        $counters[$newWhat] = 1;
    }
}

addNew('Bob', $counters);
addNew('Billy', $counters);
addNew('Bob', $counters);
addNew('Rita', $counters);

var_dump($counters);
```

and then

```
arsort($counters);
echo array_keys($counters)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arsort.The **arsort()** function sorts an associative array in descending order, according to the value.

```
$data=array("bob"=>"2","billy"=>"5");
arsort($data);
foreach($data as $x=>$x_value)
{
echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
echo "<br>";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Key=billy, Value=5
Key=bob, Value=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    'bob' => 2,
    'billy' => 5
);

function add_value($array, $index)
{
    if (isset($array[$index]))
        $array[$index] += 1;
    else
        $array[$index] = 1;
    return $array;
}

$array = add_value($array, 'bob');
$array = add_value($array, 'bob');
$array = add_value($array, 'bob');
$array = add_value($array, 'bob');

$max_indexes = array_keys($array, max($array));
```

Note that $max_indexes is an array with the max index(es), and it may contain more than one elemenent, since you can have more than one max value.